# Issue of CORS. I already add header in serverside

Tags: php, ionic-framework, server

currently i am create a small that display markers on google map. Coordinates come from mysql database but i getting the error i don't know why it's came.

ERRor - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/markers.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.7:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

markers.php

```
<?php


  //Create a connection to the database
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test");

    if (!$mysqli) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
  //The default result to be output to the browser
  $result = "{'success':false}";

  //Select everything from the table containing the marker informaton
  $query = "SELECT * FROM marker";

  //Run the query
  $dbresult = $mysqli->query($query);

  //Build an array of markers from the result set
  $markers = array();

  while($row = $dbresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $markers[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'name' => $row['name'],
      'lat' => $row['lat'],
      'lng' => $row['lng']
    );
  }

  //If the query was executed successfully, create a JSON string containing the marker information
  if($dbresult){
    $result = "{'success':true, 'markers':" . json_encode($markers) . "}";        
  }
  else
  {
    $result = "{'success':false}";
  }
 //Set these headers to avoid any issues with cross origin resource sharing issues
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-requested-with');

  //Output the result to the browser so that our Ionic application can see the data
  echo($result);

?>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, GoogleMaps) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    GoogleMaps.init();
  })
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('map', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
    controller: 'MapCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})

.factory('Markers', function($http) {

  var markers = [];

  return {
    getMarkers: function(){

      return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/markers.php").then(function(response){
          markers = response;
          return markers;
      });

    }
  }

})

.factory('GoogleMaps', function($cordovaGeolocation, Markers){

  var apiKey = false;
  var map = null;

  function initMap(){

    var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      var mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

      //Wait until the map is loaded
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){

        //Load the markers
        loadMarkers();

      });

    }, function(error){
      console.log("Could not get location");

        //Load the markers
        loadMarkers();
    });

  }

  function loadMarkers(){

      //Get all of the markers from our Markers factory
      Markers.getMarkers().then(function(markers){

        console.log("Markers: ", markers);

        var records = markers.data.markers;

        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

          var record = records[i];   
          var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(record.lat, record.lng);

          // Add the markerto the map
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: markerPos
          });

          var infoWindowContent = "<h4>" + record.name + "</h4>";          

          addInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent, record);

        }

      }); 

  }

  function addInfoWindow(marker, message, record) {

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: message
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

  }

  return {
    init: function(){
      initMap();
    }
  }

})

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration to do with Ionic :

http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html

Or if you are using google chrome you can add this plugin, it solve the problem for me :

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Hope it should help you

Comment: thanxx ...you save my day